# Owl-Carousel not working with AngularJs ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, carousel, angularjs-ng-repeat

The code below works fine without ng-repeat. But i would like to repeat all the div using ng-repeat.

```
<div id="food-menu" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="lazyOwl" data-src="/img/Services/Food/Meal-1.png" alt="Food">
        <div class="caption">
                <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
            <p>...</p>
                <div><span class="price">$ 00.00</span><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a></div>
        </div>enter code here
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But when i create the code like this, it stops working.

```
<div ng-repeat="t in test">
<div id="food-menu" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="lazyOwl" data-src="/img/Services/Food/Meal-1.png" alt="Food">
        <div class="caption">
                <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
            <p>...</p>
                <div><span class="price">$ 00.00</span><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">Button</a></div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Edit: What is the simplest way to make the ng-repeat repeat all the div along with the classes inside it. The last code that i posted displays nothing and the classes were not being repeated in each divs. Im really new to angular and jquery.

Comment: how did u solve this ng-repeat problem with owl carousel!!???

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I prepared a Plunker with your markup: http://plnkr.co/edit/0bgevXraCpWwFMpROO0h and with the appropriate Angular startup and controller is working fine.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl',  function ($scope) {
  $scope.test = ['a','b', 'c'];
});
```

-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="t in test">
       <p>{{t}}  </p>  
    </div>    
  </body>
</html>
```

You haven't paste your JS code which is the most important thing if you're going to need help on Angular related issues.
I think you should start learning the very basics from a complete tutorial, just pasting some code in the editor won't get you anywhere.

There's a terrific video-tutorial series on the AngularJS website http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/intro

This should be your starting point and reference website.

Or you can try an user created tutorial http://www.toptal.com/angular-js/a-step-by-step-guide-to-your-first-angularjs-app

Comment: I was able to make the ng-repeat work on the div, but it cannot inherit the class that owl-carousel implemented.

Comment: Which class are you talking about? And inherit where? You mean owl-theme in css? Something like .owl-theme.item ?

Comment: This shouldn't be the answer. It has nothing to do with the question.